# Comping over the Cmaj7 in "My Favorite Things"

Tags: chord-theory, jazz, songwriting, arranging

[image: My Favorite Things Head]

I am wondering if someone can give advice on how to make comping over the Cmaj7 chord in bars 5 through 8 sound more interesting.

In the first 4 bars I play E-7 to F#-7 to E-7/G back to F#-7 and that sounds pretty good, but once I get to the second four bars of just sitting on the Cmaj7 chord it sounds really boring.
Any tips on what chords or inversions I could throw in here to make this section sound like it has some motion or interest? I am comping on guitar if that makes any difference.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you literally just sitting on Cmaj7? Tell a bit of what you do for those four bars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- One option is to take a modal approach to those four bars. Accounting for the CMaj7 and the prominent use of F# in the melody, consider those four bars as being in C lydian. In that case, any chord present in that scale/mode could be used. For example, a comping pattern of CMaj7 - D7 - Em7 - D7 would lead neatly into the following A-7 - D7.
- Another similar option would be to take advantage of the close relationship between E-7 and CMaj9, the former being equivalent to a rootless voicing of the latter. Alternating between those two chords measure by measure would give some interest without substantially changing the harmony.
- Varying the rhythm can also help break up an otherwise monotonous comp. For example, comping in 2/4 (that is, two dotted quarter notes per measure) against the written 3/4 can provide enough musical interest to compensate for the static harmony.
- Like the CMaj7 / E-7 relationship, CMaj7 can be viewed as a rootless A-9. One could alternate between those two chords or near equivalently (from a theory perspective) CMaj7 - C6.

Comment: This answer gives me a lot to think about. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So the melody over Cmaj7 remains the same as it was over Em, this means that your "comping" can remain the same. This won't be boring at all. With the new basstone it will appear in a quite different dress.

Answer (score 0):

CM-Dm7-Em7-FM7.  Reference The Jazz Theory Book by Mark Levine page 27.

Answer (score -1):

There’s an E - F♯ - G - F♯ line that fits bars 1-4. And bars 5-8.  You could do something with that.

But comping is MEANT to be simple and supportive. Your turn to shine comes later.